# How do i Pass the Value To hidden using attr in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<input type="hidden" value="" id="myhidden">
```

Iam getting the Value of Button Value  using data-value attribute from button

```
var myvalue = $(this).attr("data-value");
```

I have to pass the "myvalue"  to the hidden value

```
$("#myhidden").attr("value","??????????????");
```

when i have passed "myvalue" It is not acccepting

Answer (score 1):

```
var myvalue = $(this).attr("data-value");

$("#myhidden").val(myvalue);
```

to check if it's there, you could try `alert($("#myhidden").val());` after setting the value...

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myhidden").attr("value",myvalue).serialize();
```

Comment: We are getting the object and iam converting it to a value

Comment: From your Original Post, I don't think you're getting an object... is `alert(myvalue);` alerting an `[object]` ?