# Store Attributes from Button in a Hidden field

Tags: jquery

I have two buttons. Both buttons have two attributes – “data-from“  and “data-to“. When any of the button is clicked, these attribute values need to be passed on to a hidden field and the form need to be submitted (POST). Before submitting, I need to alert the attribute values from the hidden fields also. How do I do that?

Note: The following code is written using ASP.NET Webforms.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">

<title></title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
        $('#mainDiv input[type="button"]').on('click', function () 
        {
            alert('HAi');
            $('#from').val($(this).attr('data-from'));
            $('#to').val($(this).attr('data-to'));

            //alert($('#from').val);
            //alert($('#to').val);

            $('this').closest('form').submit(); 
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainDiv">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <input type="button" 
              value="Show March Programs" 
              data-from="01-03-2012" 
              data-to="31-03-2012" />

    <input type="button" 
               value="Show 2012 Programs" 
               data-from="01-01-2012" 
               data-to="31-12-2012" />

        <input type="hidden" id="from" value="1" />

        <input type="hidden" id="to" value="2" />
</div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

READING:

1. [How do i Pass the Value To hidden using attr in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327713/how-do-i-pass-the-value-to-hidden-using-attr-in-jquery)

Comment: Two attributes with the same name `data-from`?

Comment: It was a typo. Two different attributes exist on each button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost there. It was failing on the submit function which you can use either the generic $('form') (in case you have only one form in your page  or you can change it to $('#form1'). You need to change also the action and method in your form.

Now, I see that you are using non-standard attributes to store values, this 'works' but is not syntactically correct. You might need to change it if you want to pass the validation.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
        $('#mainDiv input[type="button"]').on('click', function () 
        {
            alert('HAi');
            $('#from').val($(this).attr('data-from'));
            $('#to').val($(this).attr('data-to'));

            alert($('#from').val());
            alert($('#to').val());

            $('form').submit(); 
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="mainDiv">
  <form id="form1" runat="server" action="index.html">
    <div>
      <input type="button" 
              value="Show March Programs" 
              data-from="01-03-2012" 
              data-to="31-03-2012" />
      <input type="button" 
               value="Show 2012 Programs" 
               data-from="01-01-2012" 
               data-to="31-12-2012" />
      <input type="hidden" id="from" value="1" />
      <input type="hidden" id="to" value="2" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```